# Problema con consulta y subconsulta en ORACLE

Tags: oracle, sql, subconsultas

¿Que tal? 
Bueno como menciona el titulo, tengo un problema con una consulta un tanto compleja (o al menos para mi lo es).

Estoy aprendiendo a usar ORACLE como manejador de bases de datos y tengo un proyecto en el cual tengo que realizar en una consulta que se va a ver reflejada en un gridview.

La consulta tiene que darme las cantidades de los productos que están por llegar al almacén, para eso, ese estado es igual a 1, también se considera que un producto puede llegar en diferentes ordenes de compra por ejemplo.. hoy me pueden llegar 4 lamparas y mañana otras 4 y en otro día otras 10. de modo que en la tabla no solo me tiene que mostrar el numero 4 o el numero 10, si no que el total de todos los productos que están por llegar.
Sumándole a eso, en una orden de compra puedes estar adquiriendo mas de un solo articulo, por lo que puedes comprar el articulo con el ID 1, 5, 12, 45, etc en la misma orden de compra y estos se tienen que ir sumando y mostrarse en una tabla.

En mi consulta he implementado esto pero solamente me regresa la cantidad total de artículos que están por llegar, sin embargo no hace match el ID que debe de aparecer con la cantidad de artículos que se está comprando.

```
SELECT  ID, DESCRIPCION,
(Select sum(CANTIDAD) FROM almacen.TBL_DETALLEDEORDENDECOMPRA WHERE DETALLE IN (SELECT ID FROM ALMACEN.TBL_CATALOGO)
  AND ORDENDECOMPRA IN (SELECT ORDENDECOMPRA FROM ALMACEN.TBL_ORDENDECOMPRA WHERE ESTADOCOMPRA = 1 
    AND ordendecompra in (select ordendecompra from almacen.TBL_DETALLEDEORDENDECOMPRA where  DETALLE IN (SELECT ID FROM ALMACEN.TBL_CATALOGO )))
  ) as "Detalle De Compra"
  from almacen.tbl_catalogo A
```

[image: la consulta me regresa esto: y pues, lo que requiero es que la cantidad solo se muestre en el articulo que está en las ordenes de compra con su estado de compra en 1.... los demás artículos tienen que ir por ende en vació por que no se están comprando nada.]

Espero haber sido claro y que alguien me oriente por favor... llevo un buen rato de tiempo con esto y no logro encontrar una solución.

Saludos.
He realizado la consulta de manera ''manual'' y me regresa el dato así:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obviamente al final no estaré haciendo eso, tiene que ser dinámico por que va a ir en un SP...

al final, lo que intento realizar es que se vean TODOS los artículos en una consulta pero que se vea reflejada la cantidad que está siendo sumada por todos los detalles de las compras dependiendo del articulo...

si bien, puede haber una compra que especifique en el detalle que fue comprado el articulo 5, 10 veces, el articulo 1, 12 veces, etc etc y esas cantidades tienen que ir respectivamente en la columna de ''detalle de compra''

la tabla de catalogo contiene

ID             NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL, -- PK y FK con detalledeordendecompra 
  DESCRIPCION              VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)   NOT NULL,
  DETALLEORDENDECOMPRA     VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)  --FK con detalledeordendecompra

la tabla de ordendecompra contiene

ORDENDECOMPRA              VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)  NOT NULL,  --PK
  ESTADOCOMPRA          NUMBER(10)         NOT NULL -- fk con estadodecompra

la tabla de estadodecompra contiene

ID      NUMBER(10)                           NOT NULL, -- PK
  NOMBRE  VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)                    NOT NULL

la tabla de detalledeordendecompra contiene

ORDENDECOMPRA  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)    NOT NULL,--  PK y FK con ordendecompra
  DETALLE NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL, -- PK  y FK con catalogo (el id del producto)
  CANTIDAD       NUMBER(10)                     NOT NULL

Por cierto: el identificador de la tabla ordendecompra, tiene un identificador que es varchar, por que aqui manejan una orden de compra que contiene numeros y letras pero todas son diferentes, no se repiten y esa es su llave primaria

La tabla de detalledeordendecompra tiene llave primaria compuesta por que una orden de compra identifica al registro pero tambien en el mismo registro pueden contener mas de 2 articulos diferentes, entonces por eso es compuesta.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105817/discussion-on-question-by-hexical-problema-con-consulta-y-subconsulta-en-oracle).

Comment: Agrega las descripciones de las tablas y las condiciones de join...

Comment: Para la sumatoria no estoy usando Join... Las tablas como tal tienen mas columnas y las estoy mandando a llamar con sus respectivos join, que me funcionan bien, lo único que no me queda es  que las cantidades se vean reflejadas en la columna que tengo problema

Comment: Especificaré las tablas y columnas editando la publicación, un momento.